# Client gets undeclared checked exception, but Exception is declared to be caught

Tags: java, rmi

My RMI server interface declares a method foo() which is declared to throw RemoteException and Exception, as follows:

```
public interface Node extends RemoteService {

   public void foo() throws RemoteException, Exception;
}
```

The server implementation is:

```
public class NodeImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Node {

    public void foo() throws RemoteException, Exception {
      // Implementation - calls other stuff...
    }
}
```

My client calls foo on the server:

```
try {
  node.foo();
}
catch (Exception e) {
   System.err.print("Got exception from foo() of type " + e.getClass().getName());
   System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Now when I run the client I get:

> Got exception from foo() of type java.rmi.UnexpectedException
>   Exception: undeclared checked exception; nested exception is: 
>     java.io.InterruptedIOException: The operation timed out

Java doc says this about java.rmi.UnexpectedException:

> An UnexpectedException is thrown if the client of a remote method call
>   receives, as a result of the call, a checked exception that is not
>   among the checked exception types declared in the throws clause of the
>   method in the remote interface.

But my remote interface specifies that foo() throws Exception, and java.io.InterruptedIOException is a kind of Exception.  So why does my client get UnexpectedException?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Your client has `caught` the exception and is executing the print statements that you have declared, what is the problem?

Comment: Try to avoid throwing generic exceptions such as Exception. It would better to catch and re-throw these separate exceptions as a domain-specific exception, like ServerException.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace. Are you sure you have the current version of the code deployed at both the server and the client? and have you restarted the Registry since the last code change?

Comment: Yes, please post the full stack trace. The accepted answer doesn't appear to have answered the question.

Comment: Unfortunately the full stack trace is what I included in the original post. The target is running an ancient version of the IBM J9 JVM, which JDK1.3 compliant.

Answer (score 2):

> But my remote interface specifies that foo() throws Exception, and
>   java.io.InterruptedIOException is a kind of Exception. So why does my
>   client get UnexpectedException

Because

```
throws Exception
```

means the method can throw exception of class type `Exception` or any of its subclass type. `InterruptedIOException`  is a subclass of `Exception` so it is perfectly valid for the method to throw `InterruptedIOException` when in the signature its super type `Exception` is mentioned.

Comment: Thanks Juned - So does UnexpectedException mean that an undeclared checked exception is getting thrown further down in the server's stack?

Comment: @user604713 From your stack trace, it seems java.io.InterruptedIOException is actually happening.

Comment: You haven't explained why an exception that extends `Exception` is 'unexpected'.

Comment: @EJP Isn't already mentioned in the question and isn't very clear: Java doc says this about java.rmi.UnexpectedException:

An UnexpectedException is thrown if the client of a remote method call receives, as a result of the call, a checked exception that is not among the checked exception types declared in the throws clause of the method in the remote interface.

Comment: I know what it says. The question is why this error? `Exception` *is* declared in the `throws` clause of the method in the remote interface: `public void foo() throws RemoteException, Exception;`

Comment: From the available stack trace, we see that InterrupedIOException is being thrown by server-side code. I don't see how this qualifies as an UnexpectedException since the remote interface declares Exception among its checked exceptions. Perhaps this is a bug in the ancient J9 JVM (JDK1.3) running on the server...

Comment: @user604713 1.3 didn't have such a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect you aren't running the same version of the code at client and server. Do a clean build and redeploy everything. There seems to be a disagreement between the remote interfaces at server and client.

Comment: That may be the case- I've recompiled everything. The observed exception is rare in any case, so not easy to reproduce. I will watch for it.